# Access a string variable in another class objective c

Tags: objective-c, variables, public

Please keep in mind I am new to objective c coding and do not understand many of the concepts.

I have 2 classes that must speak to one another. Class1 declares a string variable and Class2 reads it. I am not sure of the best way to go about this but after some research here is what I have.

The error is that when I access the variable in Class2 the variable is (null).

Class1.h

```
static NSString *var;
@interface Class1 : UIViewController {

    //other variables
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *var;
@end
```

Class1.m

```
@implementation Class1
@synthesize var;

-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender;
{
    var = @"some generated variable";
    //after setting the variable I immediately call Class2
}
```

Class2.h

```
@interface Class2 : UIViewController {
    NSString *var2;
}
@end
```

Class2.m

```
#import "Class1.h"
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    Class1 *obj = [[Class1 alloc] init];
    var2 = obj.var;
    NSLog(@"%@", var2);
    //this print statement is (null)
}
```

Im just not sure where I am going wrong. If my code is unclear in any way please let me know.

Comment: You are creating an new instance of `Class1`, you are not referencing the instance which is holding the variable. You will need to pass the instance of the `Class1` where you have set the variable to `Class2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not setting the value of the property `var` in `Class1` at the init method of this class. Yo do int only when `button action` method is executed. So when you create a new instance of `Class1` in your `initWithNibName:bundle:` method in `Class2` and access it (`var2 = obj.var;`), this instance's `var` property has not been set so it has a default `nil` value.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
       Class1 *obj = [[Class1 alloc] init];
       var2 = obj.var; // <-- obj.var is not set, so it returns nil
       NSLog(@"%@", var2);
       //this print statement is (null)
    }
    return self;
}
```

In order to solve this, you could either initialize `var` in `Class1`at the init method or to have a reference to the same instance where you are running the `buttonAction` to set the var value given to `Class2`. For example, passing you `Class1` instance as an input of your `Class2` init method:

This is how you would create and initialized `Class2` instance from `buttonAction` method in **Class1.m**:

```
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender;
{
    self.var = @"some generated variable";
    //after setting the variable I immediately call Class2
    Class2 *obj2 = [Class2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourNibName"
                                           bundle:nil
                                        andClass1:self];
}
```

This would be your `Class2` init method in **Class2.m**:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
            andClass1:(Class1 *)obj
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        var2 = obj.var; // <-- obj.var will be set in buttonAction
        NSLog(@"%@", var2);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Question is not about why it is `nil`, although it is, but especially why it is not `@"some generated variable";`. And this is because a new instance is created and which is not holding the value set in the other instance.

Comment: Yes. This explanation worked. Thank you for the clear explanation as it was extremely helpful.

Comment: Wonderful edit @rckoenes. I forgot to follow the standard init method structure and to call the super's `initWithNibName` method.